# Можно ли в компоненте sale.personal.order.detail посмотреть заказы других пользователей 1C-Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня есть компонент sale.personal.order.detail в котором должны выводится заказы продавца, то есть продавец не является покупателем этого заказа. При переходе на страницу с этим компонентом открывается пустая страница если продавец не является покупателем, если же он является покупателем, то все работает хорошо.

Код вызова компонента

````
        "cwr:sale.personal.order.detail", 
        "order_seller", 
        array(
            "ID" => "$order_id",
            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "zakaz_seller",
            "PROP_1" => array(
                6
            ),
            "PROP_5" => array(
            ),
            "PROP_6" => array(
            ),
            "PROP_2" => array(
            ),
            "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y / H:m",
            "PICTURE_WIDTH" => "110",
            "PICTURE_HEIGHT" => "110",
            "PICTURE_RESAMPLE_TYPE" => "1",
            "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
            "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
            "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
            "PATH_TO_LIST" => "",
            "PATH_TO_CANCEL" => "",
            "PATH_TO_COPY" => "",
            "PATH_TO_PAYMENT" => "payment.php",
            "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
            "CUSTOM_SELECT_PROPS" => array(
            ),
            "RESTRICT_CHANGE_PAYSYSTEM" => array(
                0 => "0",
            ),
            "REFRESH_PRICES" => "N",
            "DISALLOW_CANCEL" => "N",
            "ALLOW_INNER" => "N",
            "ONLY_INNER_FULL" => "N"
        ),
        false
    );```
````